# Extract a date suffix with MomentJS to make it superscript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm following strict user interface guidelines and I need to display date suffixes in superscript (`<sup>`):

> ## 18<sup>th</sup> September 2015

MomentJS has a lot of functions for formatting dates, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to allow us to extract a date suffix (the `th` bit in the example above) without including the number before it...

> ```
>                 Token    Output
> Month           Mo       1st 2nd ... 11th 12th
> Day of Month    Do       1st 2nd ... 30th 31st
> Day of Year     DDDo     1st 2nd ... 364th 365th
> ...
> ```

Currently I'm stripping the numeric values before the suffix by using:

```
date.format("Do").replace(/\d/g, "");
--> "18th" -> "th"
```

But the problem is that this gets messy when having to display things like "18th September 2015", as I'm having to use three separate `format()` calls:

```
var dateSuffix = "<sup>" + date.format("Do").replace(/\d/g, "") + "</sup">;
date.format("DD") + dateSuffix + date.format("MMMM YYYY");
--> "18<sup>th</sup> September 2015"
```

I'm ideally looking to avoid using `replace()` altogether and to instead use something similar to this but with the `Do` part replaced with just the suffix:

```
moment(new Date()).format("DD<\\sup>Do</\\sup> MMMM YYYY");
--> "18<sup>18th</sup> September 2015"
```

Does MomentJS have any functionality to pull a date suffix by itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think MomentJS has the function you're looking for; I'd say you should go to the MomentJS site and submit it as a feature suggestion. You never know, it might even get implemented.

In the meanwhile, an alternative option might be to use the configuration options in MomentJS to change the Ordinal strings (ie the suffixes) so that they include a `<sup>` tag.

See the relevant section in the MomentJS manual here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/ordinal/

You'd end up writing a function that looks like this:

```
moment.locale('en', {
    ordinal: num => {
        const b = num % 10;
        const output = (~~(num % 100 / 10) === 1) ? 'th' :
            (b === 1) ? 'st' :
                (b === 2) ? 'nd' :
                    (b === 3) ? 'rd' : 'th';
        return num + '<sup>' + output + '</sup>';
    },
});
```

The above example is lifted directly from MomentJS's manual, with just the `return` line being modified.

Comment: That's very interesting, I wasn't aware Moment allowed for customisation like this!

Comment: The feature is mainly intended for localisation (ie translations) but does come in handy for this kind of thing too.

Comment: As of moment 2.12 the function is `moment.updateLocale('en',...)`

Answer (score 16):

I looked at this for my own project, but decided to go with a regex solution.

```
myDate.format( 'Do MMMM YYYY' ).replace( /(\d)(st|nd|rd|th)/g, '$1<sup>$2</sup>' );
```

I appreciate the OP wanted to avoid regex, but this is a simple solution that may be beneficial to others.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are all pretty good but since I was using react-moment that wasn't working for me.

I simply used the inbuilt filter function in react-moment explained well in the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#filter).

I wrote a simple string replace function as follows (note where I have placed the function):

```
...render() {
    const toSuperFilter = (sup) => {
        let res=sup.replace(/(?<=[0-9])(?:st)/i, "ˢᵗ");
        res=res.replace(/(?<=[0-9])(?:nd)/i, "ⁿᵈ");
        res=res.replace(/(?<=[0-9])(?:rd)/i, "ʳᵈ");
        res=res.replace(/(?<=[0-9])(?:th)/i, "ᵗʰ");
        return res
    }
    return (...
```

And then in the moment child component, I passed it like this:

```
<Moment filter={toSuperFilter} format="Do MMM, YYYY">
    {`${date_variable}`}
</Moment>
```

Works like a charm! here are the results:

[image: image for ref]

edit: I previously forgot to account for month names so the st in august also got replaced during testing :) I added a group that checks st after digits and that solved it. Open to any other more elegant solutions using regex. I was unable to use the  tag as it was a string in react-moment. Let me know if anyone can get that part working.

Answer (score -1):

```
D DD        1..31       Day of month
Do          1st..31st   Day of month with ordinal
DDD DDDD    1..365      Day of year
```

You can use `Do` for a day with ordinal.

I use:

```
moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY');
```

Comment: `Do` doesn't *extract* the date ordinal like the question asks, it provides the date and the ordinal together.